# C# do something if process takes longer than set time interval but not quit

Tags: c#, process, timeout

I have a .exe process that I want to wait 2 hours to it to finish.  But if it takes longer than 1 hour I would like to call a function to send a email status that this is taking long than usual.  How to call a function if it takes longer than certain time but not quit the process and still wait the full 2 hours?

How I'm calling the process

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exePath, parameterString);
var procExited = proc.WaitForExit(twohourinmilliseconds);
//do something here if taking longer than 1 hour but not quit?
int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Instead of calling `WaitForExit` you can have a poll loop that sleeps for a second, say, checks the proc status, and repeats, until some overall timeout is reached.

Comment: What is the equivalent to process getting killed by waitForExit maxe time reached, can i say proc.kill() if more than 2 hours?

Comment: I see no indication in the documentation for WaitForExit that the process gets killed if the timeout expires, so actually you can probably just use that for what you want to do.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError so the process is still running even if say I quit my c# app after WaitForExit returns?

Comment: That's the impression I get, though I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: What do you want to happen after the 2 hours have passed? Do you want to kill the process then?

Comment: No i think id rather kill my program and let user investigate

Comment: If you don't want to do anything at the 2-hours milestone, then probably your program should exit at the 1-hour milestone (after sending the email).

Comment: No because there is multiple exe im running if 1 exe then yes probably

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `async` version of `WaitForExit` - [WaitForExitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexitasync?view=net-6.0) (and making you routine `async` as well):

```
 var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exePath, parameterString);

 // Delay for an hour (3_600_000 milliseconds)
 Task delay = Task.Delay(3_600_000);

 // Asynchronously wait for two possible outcomes: 
 //  1. process completion
 //  2. delay (timeout) completion  
 if (delay == await Task.WhenAny(proc.WaitForExitAsync(), delay)) {
   // 1 hour passed, but proc is still running
   //TODO: Send notification here
 } 
 else {
   // process completed before 1 hour passed
 }
```

If you want to wait no more then **2** hours (`7_200_000` milliseconds) and you want to send a message after **1** hour wait:

```
 var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exePath, parameterString);

 // We are going to cancel proc after 2 hours (== 7_200_000 milliseconds)
 // for its completion
 using (CancellationTokenSource cs = new CancellationTokenSource(7_200_000)) {
   Task delay = Task.Delay(3_600_000, cs.Token);
   Task exe = proc.WaitForExitAsync(cs.Token);

   try {
     if (delay == await Task.WhenAny(exe, delay)) {
       // 1 hour passed, but proc is still running
       //TODO: Send notification here
     }
       
     // Keep on waiting exe
     await exe;  

     // proc succesfully completed; we are within 2 hours timeout 
     //TODO: implement normal flow here
   }
   catch (TaskCanceledException) {
     // 2 hours passed, proc execution cancelled  
     //TODO: you pobably want to send another message here
   }
 }
```

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias: you are quite right, thank you! Another `await` is required: first we wait for `exe` or `delay` (and send message if it is `delay` we get from `WhenAny`) and then we should keep on waiting on `exe` unitil we have a completion or cancellation